# Free linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list and I want to delete all nodes of it. The problem is that if I call the delete it prints out only the 1 and then it freezes. I've read some other questions like this, but I don't know why it's happening. I guess I'm just blind or something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
  int id;
  struct _node *next;
} *node;

typedef struct {
  node first;
} *head;

head newHead(node n) {
  head h = malloc(sizeof(node));
  h->first = n;
  return h;
}

node newNode(int id) {
  node n = malloc(sizeof(node));
  n->id = id;
  n->next = NULL;
  return n;
}

void delete(head h) {
  if(h->first == NULL) return;

  node current = h->first;
  while(current != NULL) {
    printf("%i", current->id);
    node tmp = current;
    current = current->next;
    free(tmp);
  }

  // free(h);
}

int main() {
  node n = newNode(1);
  head h = newHead(n);
  node n2 = newNode(2);
  node n3 = newNode(3);
  node n4 = newNode(4);
  n->next = n2;
  n2->next = n3;
  n3->next = n4;

  printf("%i", h->first->id);
  printf("%i", h->first->next->id);
  printf("%i", h->first->next->next->id);
  printf("%i", h->first->next->next->next->id);

  delete(h);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried defining [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Invariants_in_computer_science) for your list and verify that they hold? This technique is often useful when dealing with easy-to-mess-up code such as lists and such.

Comment: In your main, you set `head h = newHead(n)`, but below you did `n->next = n2;` Shouldn't it be `h->next = n2`?

Comment: @burntchowmein They are the same, but it would be ```h->first->next = n2;```

Comment: Well, that works.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `newNode` you are allocating an invalid size of memory

```
node n = malloc(sizeof(node));
                       ^^^^
```

That is instead of allocating a memory for an object of the type `struct _node` you are allocating memory for a pointer to such an object that is of the type `struct _node *`.

You need to write

```
node n = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
```

`

And you need to free memory pointed to by the pointer `h`.

The function `delete` could look like

```
void delete( head *h ) 
{
    for ( node current = ( *h )->first; current != NULL; ) 
    {
        printf("%i", current->id);
        node tmp = current;
        current = current->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    free( *h );

    *h = NULL;
}
```

and called like

```
delete( &h );
```

In this case after exiting the function the pointer `h` will be equal to `NULL`.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
  int id;
  struct _node *next;
} *node;

typedef struct {
  node first;
} *head;

head newHead(node n) {
  head h = malloc(sizeof(node));
  h->first = n;
  return h;
}

node newNode(int id) {
  node n = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
  n->id = id;
  n->next = NULL;
  return n;
}

void delete( head *h ) 
{
    for ( node current = ( *h )->first; current != NULL; ) 
    {
        printf("%i", current->id);
        node tmp = current;
        current = current->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    free( *h );

    *h = NULL;
}

int main() {
  node n = newNode(1);
  head h = newHead(n);
  node n2 = newNode(2);
  node n3 = newNode(3);
  node n4 = newNode(4);
  n->next = n2;
  n2->next = n3;
  n3->next = n4;

  printf("%i", h->first->id);
  printf("%i", h->first->next->id);
  printf("%i", h->first->next->next->id);
  printf("%i\n", h->first->next->next->next->id);

  delete( &h );

  return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1234
1234
```

The second line of the output contains test messages from the function `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

`head h = malloc(sizeof(node));` allocates the wrong size for the struct; you probably intended `head h = malloc(sizeof(head));`. Using `some_type *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo))` can help avoid errors like this.

Beyond that, there is room for trimming the code. I don't see that the `head` abstraction adds any value; it's an extra layer of indirection.

```
if(h->first == NULL) return;
```

is also superfluous since the loop will handle this case.

Please don't typedef pointers. It makes the code very difficult to follow without the explicit `*` next to the vars. Actually, I'd go a step further and not typedef the struct either. Suppressing useful information harms readability.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int id;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *make_node(int id) {
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    n->id = id;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

void free_linked_list(struct node *head) {
    while (head) {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = make_node(1);
    head->next = make_node(2);
    head->next->next = make_node(3);

    printf("%d, ", head->id);
    printf("%d, ", head->next->id);
    printf("%d\n", head->next->next->id);

    free_linked_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, I had to change this:

```
 n->next = n2;
 n2->next = n3;
 n3->next = n4;
```

to this:

```
 h->first->next = n2;
 h->first->next->next = n3;
 h->first->next->next->next = n4;
```

Comment: No way! This is the first time my "answer" was right.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. These give invalid reads invoking undefined behavior that could appear to work.